# Harriet's final exam

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, story, language

Harriet woke up in her dorm room and found a letter from the school's faculty, along with 12 small cards with some words written on them.

> Congratulations on completing the coursework in the prestigious *School of Cryptic Arts*! Your training is almost complete. Written on these cards are instructions on when and where you can collect your diploma.
>
> Of course, if you cannot manage to figure out the instructions in time, that means you have failed your training. In this case, you can pack your belongings and go home empty-handed. So you can consider this your final exam. Good luck!

The cards:

> and
>   cómo
>   herbata
>   isoäiti
>   rua
>   zwei
>   ııf Dïnısch
>   ım nırııgıîs
>   ın ıtılıını
>   ın Tıgılıg
>   pı frıncıskı
>   tırkıksı

How does Harriet figure out when and where she should show up?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Solution!

> There are 6 pairs of cards: the first card of the pair represents a word, and the second card is the language you must translate the word to (with ı replacing any vowel). Cards that are written in the same language are matched, so the pairs are as follows:
> 1. *and* + in tagalog (in English) = **at**
> 2. cómo + en italiano ("*how* in italian", in Spanish) = **come**
> 3. herbata + po francusku ("*tea* in French", Polish) = **the**
> 4. isoäiti + turkiksi ("*grandmother* in Turkish", in Finnish) = **nine**
> 5. rua + em norueguês ("*street* in Norwegian", in Portuguese) = **gate**
> 6. zwei + auf Dänisch ("*two* in Danish", in German) = **to**
> So reordering, the message is: **come to the gate at nine**

Comment: How you do the matching pairs?

Comment: _"Cards that are written in the same language are matched"_. So, e.g. 6. "zwei" and "auf Dänisch" are both in German so they match, and "zwei auf Dänisch" means "two in Danish" (in English :-)). And "two" in Danish is "to".

Comment: All correct, and very fast to boot. Nice job!